# My function Works Except When it is in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm a beginner and this is one of my first projects. I'm making a programme to solve sudokus
I wrote a function to get all the possible answers for any given square and write the answer as well as the coordinates of the blank square to a dictionary, The function works when I test it with just one square of the puzzle. The problem is when I  loop through the function with
`for x in range(0, 9): for y in range(0,9): posN(x, y)` it doesn't work and the dictionary says none of them have possible squares

```
import numpy as np
puzzleFile = np.loadtxt("Puzzle.txt", dtype=int)

rows = puzzleFile.shape[0]
cols = puzzleFile.shape[1]

# r = range 1-9, possible answers for any given square
r = []
for rN in range(1, 10):
    r.append(rN)

# p = range 0-8, possible coordinates
p = []
for pN in range(0,9):
    p.append(pN)

# splits puzzle into 3x3 boxes
u = np.array_split(puzzleFile,3,axis=0)
t = []
for a in u:
    u = np.array_split(a,3,axis=1)
    t += u


posNDict = {

}

def posN(x, y):
    
    # n = the current empty square we are working on filling
    n = puzzleFile[x, y]

    # c = all the possible answers w have not yet eliminated
    c = r

    # finds which 3x3 block n is in
    if y >= 0 and y < 4:
        if x >= 0 and x < 4:
            b = 0
        elif x > 3 and x < 7:
            b = 1
        elif x > 6 and x < 10:
            b = 2
    elif y > 3 and y < 7:
        if x >= 0 and x < 4:
            b = 3
        elif x > 3 and x < 7:
            b = 4
        elif x > 6 and x < 10:
            b = 5
    elif y > 6 and y < 10:
        if x >= 0 and x < 4:
            b = 6
        elif x > 3 and x < 7:
            b = 7
        elif x > 6 and x < 10:
            b = 8
    
    # finds all possible numbers for n
    if n == 0:
        
        for i in puzzleFile[x, p]:
            if i in c:
                c.remove(i)
        
        for i in puzzleFile[p, y]:
            if i in c:
                c.remove(i)

        for j in t[b]:
            for i in j:
                if i in c:
                    c.remove(i)
    else:
        return
    
    posNDict[str(x) + "," + str(y)] = c
    
    


for x in range(0, 9):
    for y in range(0,9):
        posN(x, y)
        

print(posNDict)
```

Does anyone have any solutions to this? I have been racking my brain.

Comment: What do you find when using a debugger?

Comment: One thing that I notice is that the `posN` function refers to several variables outside of itself. That's usually not a good thing, especially in functions that aren't simple one-liners, since it makes it *much* harder to reason about what the function does.

Comment: @mkrieger1 there is no error message or anything like that. i just print the dictionary and it is blank where all the possible answers are meant to be

Comment: FYI, you can replace the loop `for rN in range(1, 10): r.append(rN)` with `r = list(range(1, 10))`

Comment: I understand, that's what a debugger is for, to find out what your code is doing wrong.

Comment: You can't have `else: return` outside a function. What did you have there in the non-function version of the code?

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. i’ll use this instead in the future

Comment: `c = r` doesn't make a copy of `r`, both variables refer to the same list. So `c.remove(i)` also removes from `r`. And all the elements of `PosNDict` will be references to the same list.

Comment: Python allows chaining comparisons, so you can write `0 <= y < 4`

Comment: @Barmar there was never non function code i wrote it originally as part of the function. i put that in there so it didn’t add loads of unnecessary answers to my dict

Comment: Try changing `c = r` to `c = r.copy()`